# In datagridview how to 2 column that will freeze?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `datagridview` in my C# program

and when I move scroll-bar to left, I want that the 2 right columns

will freeze and don't move.

how to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Theres a properties in the columns section of the datagridview to freeze the columns.

> Go to your datagridview --> Columns
>   --> (Column you want frozen) --> Frozen = True

**EDIT:**

> After testing it seems that it will
>   only freeze the columns on the left of
>   the datagrid not the right.

**EDIT 2:**

> To get it to freeze the columns on the
>   right enable the "RightToLeft"
>   property on the datagrid. It reverses
>   the order the columns are drawn and
>   allows the rightmost columns to be
>   frozen.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["columnname"].Frozen = true;
dataGridView1.RightToLeft = Enabled;
```

Comment: +1 Great work! I haven't think about the `RightToLeft` property.

Comment: Seems like the right to left property, on .net6 at least, should be set as dataGridView1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
This does however mean that the table will be default be scrolled all the way to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You might use one of the [`DataGridViewElementStates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewelementstates.aspx) enumeration values.

Either use an index:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
```

or use the column name:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["columnName"].Frozen = true;
```

You may also use the [`DataGridViewColumnCollection.GetFirstColumn()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158919.aspx) method:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Frozen);
```

I would personnaly go with the index, since you want the two first columns to freeze. Then, when you want to change these frozen columns, you will only have to change their index in design.

As for making the two columns on the right frozen, I would simply bring them to the right, it is a more ergonomical way to do it, as most of the time, we read from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    FreezeBand(dataGridView.Rows[0]);
}

private void Button5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    FreezeBand(dataGridView.Columns[1]);
}

private static void FreezeBand(DataGridViewBand band)
{
    band.Frozen = true;
    DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    style.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    band.DefaultCellStyle = style;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.Columns["columnname"].Frozen = true;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.